# Where are these extra pixels coming from when using percentages for height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I am currently trying to use a sticky footer that I have used successfully many times before on various websites that I've built. Here is the link: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

The problem this time, is that I'm trying to make this more responsive, and hence I don't want to use a specific pixel amount for the height, so I tried switching to percentages:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -25%;
    background: lime
}

#spacer{
    background: blue;
    height: 25%;             /* This should be exactly the same as #footer height. */
}

#footer{
    background: magenta;
    height: 25%;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <link href="https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/TesterTheme/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

Content goes here.

</div><!-- End Wrapper -->

<div id="spacer"></div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I said before, when I use a specific pixel amount, like 200px, for the height (and change wrapper margin-bottom to -400px) it works fine. I've read that when you use a percentage for height, it is using a percentage of the height of the parent element and that I need to make sure to have all of the ancestor elements' heights defined. I think I do though... as body and html are the only ancestors of footer. This is actually what it does. I've measured it with a pixel ruler and the footer and spacer measure out to 25% of my view port. Yet for God knows why, a scroll bar appears on the side of my browser(Yes... it's full screen), as if the body has some how magically extended itself an extra fifty pixels or so. Please help, I've spent nine hours on this so far, searching all over and trying many different tactics but I always get the same result. Why don't the percentages yield the desired result?

Comment: Please note: I've tried this in Chrome, FF, IE and they all give the same results.

Comment: Its the `margin-bottom: -25%;` that is causing the difference in height between the footer and spacer .. also when using percentages with margins its always relative to the **width** of the element even if you're using top-bottom margin

Comment: So how do I get percentages equal to height then? Also I'm not sure what you mean about there being a difference. I probably wasn't clear enough in my description. The footer and spacer are the same height: 204px. My viewport is 814px. Even if I change the wrapper bottom-margin to -50% The body and html still come out to 814, but the footer still sits about 50 pixels lower than where firebug says the body ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of options to fix this. Using percentages in the way you are is not a good idea.. it's similar to how `this` can change in javascript.

Personally, I'd go this route for responsive.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="stuff"></div>
  <div class="stuff"></div>
  <div class="stuff"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

That way, the footer is always setting below the rest of the content. No need to specify the footer height in multiple places. Use percentages as you like with this setup.

If you're not 100% happy with it, use jQuery/javascript to stretch the content. Or even, CSS media queries.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite sure what you meant at first but what I ended up doing was just giving the content a min-height of 75% and then gave the footer a height of 25%. This seems to be working fine. It seems so obvious now. I can't believe I wasted so much time on trying to get the stupid thing to work.

Comment: It happens to the best of us. The main thing is never putting more code than is necessary. Always cascade from the top down. CSS only does so much, then it's time to look into javascript and make sure it falls back correctly. Happy coding!